# Angular 2 RC 3 Offline Template Compiler

Tags: angular, angular2-template

Can anyone please guide how to use Angular 2 offline template compilation in Angular 2 RC 3?

Comment: see if this link helps- https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular2-template-compiler

Comment: Even though they mentioned it in the changelog, I doubt is is completed and supposed to be used already.

Comment: I've just found this article http://www.syntaxsuccess.com/viewarticle/offline-compilation-in-angular-2.0

Maybe this anwers your question.

Comment: @MirekPluta, the link for this article broken. Could you please fix? Thanks